# Type 'SwinjectStoryboardOption' does not conform to protocol 'ServiceKeyOption'

Tags: swift, xcode, swinject

After I did a clean install of my project Cocoapods which worked just before the clean install, now when I compile there is that error:

```
Type 'SwinjectStoryboardOption' does not conform to protocol 'ServiceKeyOption'
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Pretty clean fix is to go to `Podfile.lock` and look for `Swinject`, set it's version to `2.6.0` instead of `2.7.x`. It will look like this:

```
  - Swinject (2.6.0)
```

As soon as `SwinjectStoryboard` releases a fix, you can just update the `SwinjectStoryboard` and it will automatically update `Swinject` to a proper version.

**The issue**

It looks like SwinjectStoryboard had a wrong dependency description in their podspec file:

```
s.dependency 'Swinject', '~> 2.6'
```

Which resulted in `cocoapods` picking any `2.x` version which is higher than `2.6`. So it mistakenly picks `2.7.x` which is not compatible with current `SwinjectStoryboard` version.

Btw looks like the fix is on the way, it is on the master branch but not yet version tagged.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by moving the Swinject to Swift 5 as part of their 2.7.0 release. At the moment of writing this, fix for it is already merged into master SwinjectStoryboard branch. What is missing is just releasing a new version.

So except of falling back to Swinject 2.6 there is also other temporary workaround (till official release would be made) - fetching the master branch content by defining in Podfile

```
pod 'SwinjectStoryboard' , :git => 'https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard.git', :branch => 'master'
```

There is a [ticket](https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard/issues/127) dedicated to this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is adding

```
func hash(into: inout Hasher) {
    
}
```

to `internal struct SwinjectStoryboardOption: ServiceKeyOption {<here>}`.

The file's path should be `Pods -> SwinjectStoryboard -> SwinjectStoryboardOption.swift`